# Java Clip unsupported control type exception

Tags: java, audio

I'm teaching a programming course, and we've been building a text adventure game in Java. I am adding some audio as one of the last steps, and it usually works. But seemingly randomly, I will get the error `Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Unsupported control type: Master Gain at java.desktop/com.sun.media.sound.AbstractLine.getControl(AbstractLine.java:149)`. This is my method body:

```
public Clip playAudio(String audioFilePath, int loopCount, float startVolume) throws Exception {

    File audioFile = new File(audioFilePath);
    
    // File exists
    if (audioFile.exists()) {
        AudioInputStream audioInput = AudioSystem.getAudioInputStream(audioFile);
        Clip clip = AudioSystem.getClip();
        clip.open(audioInput);
        FloatControl volume = (FloatControl) clip.getControl(FloatControl.Type.MASTER_GAIN); // This throws my error
        volume.setValue(startVolume);
        clip.loop(loopCount);
        return clip;
    }
    // File does not exist
    else {
        System.out.println("Audio file does not exist.");
        return null;
    }

}
```

For whatever reason, I can call this just fine on short and long audio files, all WAVs, but some trigger the error above. Once I triggered the error and then "fixed" it by just changing the startVolume amount I passed to the function.

I've tried having the program wait 50ms before trying to set the volume, changing the input levels, having only one audio file play, etc. Different files behave just fine, but for some reason this one file doesn't work. It's the only thing that changes between method calls. I have opened the clip before setting gain like I'm supposed to as well.

Comment: I wouldn't use these even for educational purposes because you re gonna get embarassed as you do right now. For me the Clip is something you use, the kids have a little dance around and that's it. Unless your kids are 3-5 y.o. I wouldn't even use Clip.